# An upper bound for $\,m_k=\min\,\{m\in N:\,mp_k+1\;\;is\;prime\}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

For each prime $p_k$ one can define
$$m_k=\min\,\{m\in N:\,mp_k+1\;\;is\;prime\}$$
Some computations suggest that
$$m_k=O\Big(\frac{2\sqrt k}{\log k}\Big)$$
**Is this estimate confirmed by analytic number theory?**

**If not, does it exist at least an elementary method to prove that $\,m_k\lt p_k$ for each $k\,$?**

Many thanks.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linnik%27s_theorem

Comment: This question on [math.se] seems related: [Smallest prime in arithmetic progressions: upper bounds?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61949)